# Knockout multiple view models - undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, frontend

I am developing a UI that has multiple viewModels packed in a master view model. You can see the structure below:

```
function commonVM() {
   self = this;

   //initialize observable variables
   self.start_searching_visible = ko.observable(true); //start searching panel visible    
};

function searchCriteriaVM() {
   self = this;

   self.window_location = ko.observable("#/");
   self.company_search_criteria_visible = ko.observable(true);    
}

appViewModel = function () { 
   self = this;

   //False if the view has already been initialized
   isInitialized = false;
   self.commonViewModel = new commonVM();
   self.searchCriteriaViewModel = new searchCriteriaVM();     
   self.commonViewModel.start_searching_visible();     
}

var test = new appViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(test);
```

I am getting a searchCriteriaViewModel undefined error. Why am i getting this? Why can i not access this variable although i have initialized in the above statement?

Comment: where you get this error...

Comment: I editied the question. I am getting the error on 
self.commonViewModel.start_searching_visible();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var` when you decalre variable. When you miss the `var` keyword, the variables are declared as global. In your case `self` first refer to `appViewModel` but when you create `commonVM`, the `self` variable is assigned with different value and then it has a different meaning globally.

However you got so many other errors - not attaching `start_searching_visible` to this/self and it can not be accessed from instances, calling `start_searching_visible` from wrong view model etc..

```
function commonVM() {
    var self = this;

    //initialize observable variables
    self.start_searching_visible = ko.observable(true); //start searching panel visible    
};

function searchCriteriaVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.window_location = ko.observable("#/");
    self.company_search_criteria_visible = ko.observable(true);
}

appViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    //False if the view has already been initialized
    self.isInitialized = false;
    self.commonViewModel = new commonVM();
    self.searchCriteriaViewModel = new searchCriteriaVM();
    self.commonViewModel.start_searching_visible();
    // self.searchCriteriaViewModel.start_searching_visible();     
}

var test = new appViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(test);
```

---

I would recommend to complete some JavaScript (OOP) course/tutorial.